# Subtract n from every element of a Clojure sequence

Tags: clojure

I assume this is a very simple question, but I can't seem to find the answer online: how do you subtract `n` from every element of a Clojure sequence? E.g subtract 4 from each element of (6 9 11) and get (2 5 7)?

I assume this should be done with `map`, and I know that for the special case of subtracting 1 I can do `(map dec (sequence))`, but how do I do it for any other case?

For what it's worth, I figured out eventually that `(map - (map (partial - n) (sequence))` technically does work, but it's clearly not how this is meant to be done.

---

For anyone who lands here from search and has a slightly different problem: if you want to subtract every element of a Clojure sequence *from* n, you can do that with `(map (partial - n) (sequence))`

Similarly, for multiplying every element of a Clojure sequence by `n` you can do `(map (partial * n) (sequence))`

For adding `n` to every element of a Clojure sequence `(map (partial + n) (sequence))`

I found that answer in [these Clojure docs](http://clojure-doc.org/articles/language/collections_and_sequences.html) so I assume it's idiomatic, but obviously I'm not able to vouch for that myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An anonymous function literal is convenient here:

```
> (map #(- % 4) [6 9 11])
(2 5 7)
```

The `#(- % 4)` form is short-hand for the anonymous function in

```
> (map (fn [x] (- x 4)) [6 9 11])
(2 5 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a [combinatory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic) expression for the function you want, try `(comp - (partial - 4))`:

```
=> (map (comp - (partial - 4)) '(6 9 11))
(2 5 7)
```

Remember that `+` and `-` are just ordinary named Clojure functions. The function that you need is probably not worth naming, so you express it directly as `#(- % 4)` or `(fn [n] (- n 4))`, or as above.

It is also worth remembering that `map` is lazy, so can deal with endless sequences:

```
=> (take 10 (map (comp - (partial - 4)) (range)))
(-4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5)
```

Answer (score -2):

This can be achieved through maps. Clojure maps takes a function and list as an argument.
Synatax:

> (map (function) (seq))

```
test=> (map (fn[arg] (- arg 4) ) '(7 8 9) )
(3 4 5)
test=> (map (fn[arg] (- arg 4) ) [7 8 9] )
(3 4 5)
```

Map can take function in shorthand notation too.

> ## (- % 4)

. Here % is argument passed. Defaults to first argument. %1 to explicitly say first argument

```
test=> (map #(- %1 4) [7 8 9])
(3 4 5)
test=> (map #(- % 4) [7 8 9])
(3 4 5)
```

Comment: Maps, the data structures, have nothing to do with map the function. Map the function applies a function f on every element in a sequence. A map data structure is storing values  at keys.